# Cannot import asStateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

Android Studio autopopulate isn't able to recognize `kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow` for some reason.

[image]

Here is a snippet of my project build.gradle:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.1.0-alpha02"
    kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.5.21"
}

implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please don't post code as image, replace it with real code. What type `feedFlow` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asStateFlow` is only for MutableStateFlows and upcasts them to read-only StateFlow, so it’s pointless to call it here since you are immediately following it up with another function call. If you’re trying to convert a regular Flow into a StateFlow, you need to use `stateIn`, not `asStateFlow`. `asStateFlow()` is for making a public read-only (and cast-proof) version of a private MutableStateFlow By "cast-proof", I mean casting it to MutableStateFlow after the conversion will fail.

I haven’t used Compose yet, but from what I’ve briefly read, I think you can directly call `collectAsState` on a cold Flow anyway so you don’t need to do a conversion.